# Are the visible matter and dark matter separately segregated?

Tags: dark-matter

I am having difficulty in visualising dark matter. Dark matter does not interact electromagnetically. Dark matter is inferred gravitationally.
However it is not clear whether dark matter is present everywhere or is it segregated at some place like black holes?

If dark matter is segregated at some place like center of galaxy then do we assume so ? Why it can’t be present everywhere?

Comment: The answer is that we simply don't know -- we only know some rough information, e.g. that there's more near the center and less near us, and that the distribution is roughly spherically symmetric. Also, those are all statements about the average density; we don't know if DM consists of isolated particles flying around, or if it's clumped into small objects, or something else.

Comment: It's definitely not segregated or concentrated at the center of the galaxy, because it determines the motion of stars all the way out to the edges and beyond.  You can look up dark matter maps or visualizations online to see what the distribution has to be based on gravitational observations.

Comment: We don't expect (much) clump formation in dark matter because its non-gravitational interactions are tiny. So dark matter particles within a halo  can convert energy back & forth between kinetic & potential, but they can't lose that energy (eg by getting hot and radiating), so the halo can't condense.

Comment: Here's a recent DM question on our sister site that you may enjoy:  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/55070/16685 To understand DM theory it's essential to understand the virial theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem

Comment: @PM2Ring How do we know that "its non-gravitational interactions are tiny"? Obviously, the interactions with matter *observable to us* is tiny, but do we know anything about interaction between different dark matter constituents?

Comment: Fair point, @Gyro. I should've said that from our observations, the non-gravitational interactions of DM *appear* to be negligible. Perhaps you can ask a fresh question about possible non-gravitational interactions between different dark matter constituents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dark matter appears to be broadly distributed on galactic scales.
There is not much evidence for it clumping on small scales - as expected if it only interacts gravitationally. In the Milky Way, although it appears to be centrally concentrated, we know it has to much more broadly (and spherically) distributed compared to the "normal" matter we see in stars and gas. So that is segregation in some sense - "normal" matter can interact, lose energy by radiation and fall deeper into gravitational potential wells.

Just how "smoothly" dark matter is distributed on very small scales depends on what it is. It could be in lumps of mass of $10^{20}$ kg in the form of [primordial black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_black_hole) or it could be in the form of [mass ive particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particle) of 100-1000 times the mass of a proton, or maybe it doesn't exist at all and there is some [other problem with physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamic).

As a footnote, it appears eminently possible to separate normal and dark matter. The most famous example is the "Bullet Cluster". Here, we see two interacting clusters that have passed through each other. The mass of the individual clusters is betrayed by gravitational lensing studies and is concentrated in two clumps that are also marked by concentrations of galaxies. However, the hot "normal" intracluster gas, probed by X-ray observations, appears to have piled up in the interaction region between the clusters.

[image: Bullet cluster]

*Bullet Cluster - the contours indicate the overall mass distribution. The coloured regions indicate X-ray emission from hot gas.*