# Interactions within constituents of dark matter

Tags: dark-matter, interactions

Inspired by [Are the visible matter and dark matter separately segregated?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/787088/102232) I wonder if the constituents (I don't say *particles*, as we don't know) have actions and forces among themselves, that we cannot detect directly from our *observable* matter.

Might it be that there is a mirror world with the same forces as in our observable world, but just within themselves? Maybe even more than one, given that the dark matter has more mass than the observable one.

As of now, we can "observe" the dark matter only by interpreting gravitational effects.

If there should be any internal forces in dark matter, there should be a difference in clustering. Unfortunately, this is hard to detect.

Is there any theory about that, or experimentation going on, or even results?

Comment: have a look at the various hypothesis for dark matter within the mainstream particle standard model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Composition

Comment: @annav I did so, but it does not refer to any study about possible interaction between dark matter and dark matter. Maybe there is simply not much known about it. And besides, I don't trust Wikipedia in any deeper aspects of science.

Comment: *I don't trust Wikipedia in any deeper aspects of science.* In my opinion, Wikipedia is considerably more reliable than this site is, unless you are extremely selective about whose answers you pay attention to here.

Comment: @Ghoster I am, I really am. In this very case, I trust wikipedia to mirror truly what has been published and given enough citations. But they lack understanding, deliberately. Is it crude to cite "Buy horse-dung. A billion flies cannot err"?

Comment: How would such interactions among different constituents of dark matter affect the observable universe? If we cannot see it we cannot construct scientific theories about it.

Comment: @GyroGearloose if one of the particle composition  guesses shown in the list I linked  is true, the interaction between those particles will be governed by the standard model of particle physics interactions between them. Such a model might be tested if one could do an experiment where a lot of dark matter is indicated by the rotation curves, but not possible  at this time.

Answer (score 0):

There have been suggestions along these lines, and they are generally known as [hidden sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_sector) theories. The problem is that there is no (convincing) evidence, neither experimental not theoretical, that anything like this exists. As such we have to dismiss it as speculation - though interesting speculation.

Off topic, the science fiction author Stephen Baxter created just such a scenario in his [Xeelee sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeelee_Sequence) novels. The dark sector even has an intelligent life form called the [photino birds](https://xeelee.fandom.com/wiki/Photino_Birds).

Comment: Your link to "hidden sector" on Wikipedia, I read it as such: there is speculation (just as mine) but we don't know (just like me). I was hoping for some ongoing, prepared or at least proposed experiments.

Answer (score 0):

> “If there should be any internal forces in dark matter, there should
> be a difference in clustering. Unfortunately, this is hard to detect.”

This is an interesting thought. We can observe dark matter by things like gravitational lensing, but through observing images like that of the [bullet cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1e0657_scale.jpg) we can see what the aftermath of a collision of two clusters of dark matter might look like. It seems that the dark matter does not interact with itself in the same way that normal matter does. This would suggest that there couldn’t be a ‘mirror world’ with the same forces as our visible world.

That’s not to say that dark matter doesn’t self-interact in some other, more subtle way though, possibly producing an invisible world that is different to ours.

Answer (score -3):

No, since dark matter is just neutrinos. Catch up with the science:

https://forums.space.com/threads/resolution-of-the-dark-matter-mystery.61868/

Comment: This is not main stream science.

Comment: Correct, as it shouldn't be either, due to the several cosmological flaws that are known to exist in the current main stream science and which are corrected in this alternative model.

Comment: First, I did not down-vote, but will not upvote either. Even if your statement were true, which I doubt, do we really know if neutrinos among themselves  do only interact by gravity and the weak force, and not also by something else?

Comment: No, we don't know that about neutrinos. However, compared to what could otherwise be expected to be possible in terms of interactions of dark matter with itself, a lot of that can then be ruled out, already just by the fact that neutrinos barely interact with matter in general, for example, which should significantly help in reducing the search space.